# Magento2.3: Cannot edit the address in Myaccount dashboard

Tags: magento2.3, address, edit, myaccount

I have tried to change the address via account dashboard but its not working and I'm getting the below error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: region in /var/www/html/butterflynov22/butterfly/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Address/Edit.php on line 122
```

So I have changed to the default luma theme and I can edit the address without issue.

**Edit.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Edit customer address template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit
 */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $addressHelper */
$addressHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address');
$requiredAttributesPrechecked = $block->getData('required_attributes_prechecked');
?>
<form class="form-address-edit address-edit-wrap" action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-hasrequired="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <fieldset class="fieldset myacc-fieldset-edit">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Contact Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSuccessUrl() ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getErrorUrl() ?>"/>
        <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>
        <div class="address-row-wrap">
            <div class="col-6">
        <?php if ($addressHelper->isAttributeVisible('company')): ?>
        <div class="field company single-row <?php if (in_array('company', $requiredAttributesPrechecked)): ?>required<?php endif; ?>">
            <label class="label" for="company"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Company') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Company') ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" class="input-text my-account-input <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $addressHelper->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <?php if ($addressHelper->isAttributeVisible('telephone')): ?>
            <div class="field telephone single-row <?php if (in_array('telephone', $requiredAttributesPrechecked)): ?>required<?php endif; ?>">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text my-account-input
                 <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $addressHelper->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="telephone"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php if ($addressHelper->isAttributeVisible('fax')): ?>
        <div class="field fax">
            <label class="label" for="fax"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Fax') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="fax" id="fax" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Fax') ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getFax()) ?>" class="input-text my-account-input<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $addressHelper->getAttributeValidationClass('fax') ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset myacc-fieldset-edit">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Address') ?></span></legend><br>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $addressHelper->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
        <div class="field street required">
            <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('street') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStreetLine(1)) ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text my-account-input
                 <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_streetValidationClass ?>"/>
                <div class="nested">
                    <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                    <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $addressHelper->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                        <div class="field additional">
                            <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_i ?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Street Address %1', $_i) ?></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStreetLine($_i)) ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Street Address %1', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_i ?>" class="input-text my-account-input<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_streetValidationClass ?>"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ($addressHelper->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
            <div class="field taxvat">
                <label class="label" for="vat_id"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('vat_id') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="vat_id" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('vat_id') ?>" class="input-text my-account-input<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('vat_id') ?>" id="vat_id"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="address-row-wrap">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="field city required">
                    <label class="label" for="city"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?>" class="input-text my-account-input <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="field region required">
                    <label class="label" for="region_id"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="validate-select region_id my-account-input" <?= (!$block->getConfig('general/region/display_all')) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';?>/>
                            <option value=""><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Please select a region, state or province.') ?></option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="input-text my-account-input<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>"<?= (!$block->getConfig('general/region/display_all')) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';?>/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="address-row-wrap">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="field zip required">
                    <label class="label" for="zip"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international my-account-input<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>"/>
                        <div role="alert" class="message warning" style="display:none">
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="field country required">
                    <label class="label" for="country"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <?php $userDefinedAttributes = $block->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes'); ?>
        <?php if ($userDefinedAttributes):?>
            <?= $userDefinedAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if ($block->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __("This is your default billing address.") ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set billing">
                <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox"/>
                <label class="label" for="primary_billing"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Use as my default billing address') ?></span></label>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1"/>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($block->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __("This is your default shipping address.") ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set shipping">
                <input type="checkbox" id="primary_shipping" name="default_shipping" value="1" class="checkbox"/>
                <label class="label" for="primary_shipping"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Use as my default shipping address') ?></span></label>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1"/>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" data-action="save-address" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Save Address') ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Save Address') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Go back') ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#form-validate": {
            "addressValidation": {
                "postCodes": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getPostCodeConfig()->getSerializedPostCodes(); ?>
            }
        },
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false') ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But If I change the theme to our extended luma theme, its not working and It shows the above mentioned error.

Can anyone please help me to rectify this issue?

Comment: Can you pls upload your theme's address/edit.phtml file?

Comment: @RohanHapani, I have included the edit.phtml file in question section.

Comment: We just copied the edit.phtl from core and pasted it on our theme with our custom css class names. We haven't changed anything in edit.phtml

Comment: No. I said about app/design/vendor/module/Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml file

Comment: @RohanHapani We haven't have the edit.phtml in the path as you said.

Comment: However, we have edit.phtml in the path: app/design/frontend/vendor/Module/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/address/edit.phtml. I have added that code in question.

Answer (score 1):

When InputException is thrown in \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost::execute then PostValue sets in AddressFormData and redirect performs to
\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit. As a result error occurs because in array AddressFormData doesn't exist yet this
element('region').

Solution: create the after plugin

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Controller\Address\FormPost;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost;

class FixAddressFormData extends FormPost
{
    public function afterExecute(FormPost $subject, Redirect $result): Redirect
{
    $addressFormData = $subject->_getSession()->getAddressFormData();
    $addressFormData['region'] = isset($addressFormData['region']) ? $addressFormData['region_id'] : null;
    $subject->_getSession()->setAddressFormData($addressFormData);
    return $result;
}
```

}